# iOS base64 issue

Tags: ios, base64

The base64 string is

```
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
```

And I am using

```
NSData *plainData = [plainString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *base64String = [plainData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
NSLog(@"%@", base64String);
```

to decode this base64 sting but the result base64sting is null.
Is there something wrong with this base64 sting?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:base64String options:0];
NSString *decodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decodedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: The result string is null too, so I think maybe the base64 string is wrong... Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

This string is successfully decoded with:

```
NSString *string = @"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";

NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:string options:0];
NSLog(@"data = %@", data);
```

That `NSLog` will show us the hex representation of the `NSData`:

```
695fd4fa 128e0215 c70f20ab 9ed5f1c8 88137731 0330e0ba 66df9f53 b9103d89 
5ac81f1c 5d64468c 1956be70 3b8b261a 879d2557 cede6e11 3d3eab17 8d9ff76b 
4edcf587 36e758da 1a516813 fd92d0a8 87965314 484f2afa 517f7994 4eda243d 
c28eaf31 377e8939 29e36d5c 05096e2e 5d05cee4 79970a8c ab0d97fc e619862d 
fff61a38 2507ddf2 07b4db63 f43adb56 19510faa 64e5c23b ace27425 ca6fa2f4 
e1f1cf8d 64406734 4537fd1a ceecac81 ee19593c 3bcc4d0a 210cb8e9 a73177e5 
41d08f82 cc0cce99 301f14bb f588ee27 2a61738d 3dfe2293 2ba33031 973fa0cb 
724f1106 52aa5da1 e10dc05f 05ee2357 0682e961 d05d1dde d92effe6 0be4a4b2 
9142d0c3 4f0cb614 2f4137cd 394e42ea 0b9a3506 093df3d5 aa5da387 4b06a372 
ee12e752 c074d4ef dd99498d ada90f49 31ff8d20 5b0ad213 f0980626 43d3f006 
fbfe83ba 0a73a10e d772d6de d8c6a3b4 ce55ee96 b0723079 744a3f42 9e0dcc43 
f79a6a55 5d1f1133 b3d6a092 e0e8e062 661dd285 7fe89fde 2dbf6057 a0c83098 
68a54915 469200ce 6ced08e5 ac12a126 dab20eb5 96a9b93e d79123c6 17ee7c37 
2033ae31 9e056cae 4a352d42 7bb429e5 bcadf7d3 072589cc a5676e49 7cc76e25 
0a5a1831 0d6ca0e1 4fb5b78a 711b57e8 3424f1a1 e2fcf68e 796fe558 ed3b998b 
e73ecc18 aa0e3b69 cf32a9ac 381be489
```

So, it appears to be a well-formed base64 string, though it's not immediately obvious what this data represents. Regardless, I hope this illustrates how you can extract the binary payload from the base64 string.